# How to allow single mouse click in Gtk.FileChooserDialog?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk

Below is a simplified example code for a `Gtk.FileChooserDialog` widget that I had adapted from the [Gtk documentation](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#id2). To select a file or a folder or activate any in this widget, presently I have to place the mouse pointer over the item and double click it. What I would like instead to happen is to use a single mouse click to do the selection and activation. How do I set this up for this widget?

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class FileChooserWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="FileChooser Example")

        box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(box)

        button1 = Gtk.Button("Choose File")
        button1.connect("clicked", self.on_file_clicked)
        box.add(button1)

    def on_file_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("Open clicked")
            print("File selected: " + dialog.get_filename())
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel clicked")

        dialog.destroy()


win = FileChooserWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`"selection-changed"` signal](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/FileChooser.html#Gtk.FileChooser.signals.selection_changed) like this:

```py
def selection_changed (filechooser, udata):
    print ("selected ", filechooser.get_filename()) # GtkFileChooser method
    if True:                                        # some selection checking
        filechooser.response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)   # GtkDialog method

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(...)
dialog.connect ("selection-changed", selection_changed, None)
response = dialog.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    pass
elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
    pass
dialog.destroy()
```

But this signal is emitted every time user interacts with filechooser, even when user changes folder with breadcrumb-buttons. It will be up to you to determine, whether it's time to respond with Ok, Cancel or don't respond at all.

Futhermore, the user may be confused, that a dialog which requires pressing `Ok` or `Enter` in literally every other app behaves otherwise in your app.